# Printf print whitespace depending on space taken by other printed values

Tags: c

I'm doing a small RPG-textbased game in c, as an introductory exercise for C.

So, I'm doing some prints and also printing some integers inside those prints.

Currently, my very simple example looks like this (this is just with hardcoded values for sake of the example):

```
int myHealth = 200;
int monsterhealth = 200;
printf("       | You    |  Monster  | \n");
printf("Health | %d    | %d       | \n", myHealth, monsterhealth);
```

Which prints to this:

```
       | You    |  Monster  | 
Health | 200    | 200       |
```

But if the number instead only has one digit, like 1, then it has the simple issue that the text becomes a little bit offset, like this:

```
       | You    |  Monster  | 
Health | 1    | 1       |
```

This seems like a very simple issue, and I guess I could solve it by not having tables in this way, but now I got a little stubborn.

What is the cleanest way of adding some padding to a string when the integer doesnt take up as much space?

Comment: `printf("test | %d | %4d | %-6d | %08d | ...\n", 42, 42, 42, 42);`

Comment: This is nice! however in my use case the numbers will change during the run of the program and the amouint of whitespace should depend on this changing value. Thus I need something that isnt hardcoding whuitespace, but can change dynamically depending on the size of the value

Comment: In that case you can use `*` :-) ie `int white_space = 5/*or some function for the value*/; printf("| %*d |\n", white_space, 42);`

Comment: Isn't it restricted by the length of the headings? Note you can format them in the same way too.

Comment: You probably DON"T want the total space (number + whitespace) to change, which is precisely what using a fixed field size does.  So you want a fixed field size based on th size of your header strings.

Comment: @ChrisDodd yes, how do I do this?

Comment: @pmg This seems like the most viable approach. The only thing is that I have to write a lot of code checking the integers, how much space they take up etc, and then adjust these variables that are to be passed for *

Comment: Why does “Monster” have two spaces before it when “You” has only one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a field size to specify how much space a number (or string) should take -- whitespace will be added to make it (at least) that size.  A positive number will add space on the left (right justified), while a negative number will add it on the right (left justified).  So you can do something like:

```
#define NUM_STATS 2
struct Character {
    char *name;
    int  stats[NUM_STATS];
};

const char *stat_names[NUM_STATS] = { "Health", "AC" };

// character[0] is the player, others are monsters
struct Character characters[MAX_CHARACTERS];
int num_characters;

void print_info() {
    printf("%-8s |", "");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_characters; ++i)
        printf("%-4s |", character[i].name);
    printf("\n");
    for (int s = 0; s < NUM_STATS; ++s) {
        printf("%-8s |", stat_names[s]);
        for (int i = 0; i < num_characters; ++i) {
            int len = strlen(character[i].name);
            if (len < 4) len = 4;
            printf("%*d |", -len, character[i].stats[s]); }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

If you have too many characters, this will wrap (and look ugly), but you can deal with that by keeping track of how wide your printing is (and how wide your screen is) and splitting up the table in that case.

Comment: hm, this code is c++ right? also I'm quite confused by it with regards to the "characters" list, why is there a list of characters?

Comment: No, this is C code.  `Characters' are game characters -- players or monsters.  Having an array of them means you can have different numbers at different times.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the cleanest way of adding some padding

Determine minimum width for each column and use a minimum *field width* via `"*"`.

Use `"-"` flag to left justify.

```
  int myHealth = 200;
  int monsterhealth = 200;

  int cAt = 7;
  int cYou = 7;
  int cMon = 7;

  printf("%*s | %-*s | %*s |\n", //
      cAt, "", cYou, "You", cMon, "Monster");
  printf("%*s | %-*d | %*d |\n", //
      cAt, "Health", cYou, myHealth, cMon, monsterhealth);
  printf("%*s | %-*d | %*d |\n", //
      cAt, "One", cYou, 1, cMon, 1);
```

Sample Output

```
        | You     | Monster |
 Health | 200     |     200 |
    One | 1       |       1 |
```